# Getting error: Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data - In this almost valid code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For the following code getting output

```php
$response=array();
    
$response['wheel_deg_end'] = (360*(ceil($wheel->wheel_spin_time/3))) + (360 - (($wheel_slice_number * 30) - 30)) + rand(-5,5);
$response['wheel_time_end'] = $wheel->wheel_spin_time * 1000;
$response['success'] = true;
                    
$ab = json_encode($response,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo $ab;
```

Output:

```json
"{"wheel_deg_end":1743,"wheel_time_end":10000,"success":true}"
```

and error in Json parse:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    url: couponspining_ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        action: 'couponspining_wheel_run',
        form_data: form_data,
        preview_key: this.preview_key
    },
    context: this,
}).done(function(json){
    this.submit_form_done(jQuery.parseJSON(json));
});
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3
> column 1 of the JSON data
> submit_form http://localhost/shopify-php-app/src/public/assets/js/couponspining1.js:210

Comment: What is _"almost valid code"_?

Comment: _"unexpected character at **line 3** column 1"_ - The shown output only has one line. So there's something missing. Check the response in the network tab.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you show a dump of `$response` before it's JSON encoded?

Comment: you can use `code block` for `code section` in you question/answer that will help you to `formatted` and make question/answer good and easy to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the parse json line from

```
this.submit_form_done(jQuery.parseJSON(json));
```

to

```
this.submit_form_done(json);
```

Because if the configuration of your AJAX call is having dataType: json you'll get a JavaScript object so it's no longer necessary to use JSON.parse().

Answer (score -1):

`"{"wheel_deg_end":1743,"wheel_time_end":10000,"success":true}"` is not a valid json string.

Which should be `{"wheel_deg_end":1743,"wheel_time_end":10000,"success":true}`

Comment: `json_encode()` will always return valid JSON. As there's no indication that something messes with the output of `json_encode()` after it has been `echo`ed this won't be an actual problem.

Answer (score -2):

Set the content type to json:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: couponspining_ajaxurl,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: {
    action: "couponspining_wheel_run",
    form_data: form_data,
    preview_key: this.preview_key
  },
  context: this
}).done(function(json) {
  this.submit_form_done(jQuery.parseJSON(json));
});
```

Comment: `contentType` refers to the data being sent, not received.